# Why does Apple Mail not provide default color font choice?

Tags: email, font, color

After switching from PCs I was astonished to find I could only write emails in black, unless I wanted to take extra steps to change the black to another color, wasting time.  Is it so difficult to provide default color?  It's done for email "quote levels."

Comment: Unfortunately, “Apple knows best” for things like this. It is not configurable outside the options available for accessibility. You could investigate alternative email clients like Thunderbird or Postbox.

Comment: Why is the Mail-Preferences-Fonts & Colors not working for you?

Comment: What is the setting in Mail Preferences -> Composing-> Message Format?

Answer (score 0):

Apple Mail, since at least 10.4, has never provided a way to set a default font or color that will be seen by recipients.  The preferences settings are for local viewing only. Many have asked for this to be changed, but they clearly do not care. You have to use another email client or one of the addons which have been created to compensate for this (whose names escape me at the moment).